# Python. Скачать видео с сайта доступное для авторизованного пользователя

Tags: python, парсер, request, download, parse

Ребят, привет.

Подвернулась мелкая работёнка.

Нужно было спарсить сайт, залогиниться на нём и скачать видео со страниц.

Спарсить - спарсил, залогиниться - залогинился, получил ссылку на скачивание.
Но как скачать её, не знаю, с таким не сталкивался. Подскажите, куда копать и что юзать.

В общем сайт на протоколе https.

Авторизацию на сайте прохожу, вот так.

```
s = requests.Session()

def login():
    s.get(HOST, proxies=PROXY_DICT)

    data = {'username': LOGIN,
            'pass': PASS,
            'remember_me': 1,
            'action': 'login',
            'email_link': ELINK
            }

    r = s.post(HOST_AJAX_LOGIN, data=data, proxies=PROXY_DICT)

    return r
```

Весь парсинг проходит с помощью сессии "s", для получение ссылок доступных только для авторизованных пользователей.
Так-же, нужно использоваться прокси, так как сайт из моего города, увы не доступен.

Дело в том, что получив ссылку на скачивание, она не доступна для скачивания в других программах или с браузера. Каждый раз есть небольшое, на 5 знаков, отличие в ссылке. Пусть и опыта у меня нет, я предположил, что ссылка дается именно на эту сессию (или все дело в куках?).

Соотвественно, для скачивания нужно эту сессию же и использовать.

В общем, ребят. Помогите разобраться с вопросом) А то даже не знаю куда смотреть)

P.S. Пробовал сделать так (тупо), но, никакой реакции. Программа просто бесконечно пытается получить файл.

```
 f = open(r'file.mp4', "wb")
 ufr = s.get(url, proxies=PROXY_DICT)
 f.write(ufr.content) 
 f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, не имею возможности проверить свою догадку, но подозреваю, что видео отдается вам в качестве потока данных. То есть, это не цельный файл одним куском, а небольшие кусочки, посылаемые поочереди через промежутки времени.

Пример работы с такими данными [есть в документации Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#streaming-requests).

В вашем случае, возможно, код должен быть таким:

```py
resp = requests.get(r'https://addr/to/vidoe.mp4', stream=True)

with open(r'file.mp4', "wb") as output:
    for buf in resp.iter_lines():
        if buf:
            output.write(buf)
```